# Combine multiple arrays and convert it to another object array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, combinations

**I saw many similar questions like this. But none of them helped me to fulfill my need. So I'm posting this question.**

I have multiple arrays as per the users' choice. As an example, I will use 2 arrays here.

```
color = [{id: 1, name: "Red"}, {id: 2, name: "Green"}, {id: 1, name: "Blue"}]
size = [{id: 1, name: "Small"}, {id: 2, name: "Medium"}]
```

I want to get all possible combinations of given arrays and add some keys on top of that as an output.

My expected output is something like the below.

```
[{"color": "Red", "size": "Small", "price":0, "Quantity": 0},
{"color": "Red", "size": "Medium", "price":0, "Quantity": 0},
{"color": "Green", "size": "Small", "price":0, "Quantity": 0},
{"color": "Green", "size": "Medium", "price":0, "Quantity": 0},
{"color": "Blue", "size": "Small", "price":0, "Quantity": 0},
{"color": "Blue", "size": "Medium", "price":0, "Quantity": 0}]
```

If the user gives 3 arrays then it should create the combination accordingly but the properties `"price"` and `"Quantity"` will be added to the combination.

Please suggest to me how can I achieve this in Angular?

Comment: Where is `price` and `quantity` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go through the lists and build the objects:

```js
const colors = [{id: 1, name: "Red"}, {id: 2, name: "Green"}, {id: 1, name: "Blue"}]
const sizes = [{id: 1, name: "Small"}, {id: 2, name: "Medium"}]

const otherProps = {price:0, Quantity: 0}
const res = colors.flatMap(color => sizes.map(size => ({color: color.name, size: size.name, ...otherProps})))
console.log(res)
```

If you have an arbitrary number of arrays, you need to find a way to specify keys for it, for example by putting them into an object:

```js
const data = {
  color: [{id: 1, name: "Red"}, {id: 2, name: "Green"}, {id: 1, name: "Blue"}],
  sizes: [{id: 1, name: "Small"}, {id: 2, name: "Medium"}],
  stuff: [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]
}
const otherProps = {price:0, Quantity: 0}

const result = Object.entries(data)
  .map( ([propName, values]) => values.map(v =>({[propName]: v.name})))  // build the key-value pairs, i.e. [{color: 'Red'}, ...] 
  .reduce( (groups, props) => groups.length === 0 ? props : 
    groups.flatMap(group => props.map(prop => ({...group, ...prop, ...otherProps})))  // add new properties to existing groups
  );

console.log(result)
```